# Is there a desktop status widget for Jenkins?

Tags: linux, jenkins, widgets

At our company, we use Nagstamon to monitor our Nagios alerts.
It's a standalone app that doesn't require a web browser, and installs on Linux.

[image: Nagstamon]

Is there a similar widget to monitor Jenkins dashboard from a Linux desktop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For various systems:

- [Mac/RSS clients](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/hudsonTracker)
- [Linux/Windows](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hudson+Tray+Application)
- [Unknown Windows](http://code.google.com/p/notifier-jenkins/)
- [Windows Vista/7](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hudson+Vista+Gadget)
- [Android](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Mood+monitoring+widget+for+Android)